# While looping dryscrape doesn't work

Tags: python

I have a problem with dryscrape.
I've created a small script which scrapes a holiday website for prices and compares them against a desired price.
It should do this in an interval of maybe hourly or once a day. However I can't seem to loop the script.

The first run works always fine and the second fails because the variables I compare are empty.

After some testing I found out that the dryscrape part returns empty data on the second run but I don't know why. Does maybe someone of you know what I'm doing wrong? The source to the code can be found here:

https://git.2li.ch/Nebucatnetzer/price_checker/src/test

specifically here:

https://git.2li.ch/Nebucatnetzer/price_checker/src/master/price_checker.py

And this is the output of a test run.
200 is the return webserver return code of the first run and 0 the return code of the second run.

```
[andreas@gwyn price_checker]$ ./price_checker.sh
200
No Match
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andreas/git_repos/price_checker/price_checker.py", line 115, in <module>
    if website.extract_price() < settings.price:
  File "/home/andreas/git_repos/price_checker/price_checker.py", line 64, in extract_price
    lowest_price = min(int(s) for s in prices)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

What I've tried so far:

- Let it do the second run after an hour to avoid getting blocked by
  the server
- deleting the session object
- killing webkit after I got the
  page data
- reseting the session after I retrieved the data

The only thing which so far really works is a cronjob which executes the script in intervals. However I would prefer to have the whole setup contained in the python script and it's config file. It's even works with an interval of 1 minute.

Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all, if you want something to run at regular intervals you can use Python schedule. Secondly, the variables you're setting i.e. prices, they need to be global so that every function can operate on them as desired. Otherwise you just need to pass parameters to the functions, not actual data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've found out that the script works just fine but the site was causing problems.